# Multiclass-classification of stages in colorectal cancer data

Tags: machine-learning, bioinformatics, multiclass-classification

I'm working on a project with colorectal cancer stage multiclass-classification using Gene Expression Data. My dataset contains 11 Biomarkers. The results from the classification are around 40%. I have tried different models for classification with KNN, SVM, neural network..., and also I have tried algorithms from ensemble machine learning. Has anyone has any idea what can I do with the dataset to improve the results?

Answer (score 0):

To decide what to do next, you will need some metrics:

1. How well can a team of human experts classify the data?
2. What is the model accuracy on the training dataset?
3. What is the model accuracy on the testing dataset?

If the training accuracy is much worse than human experts, you should increase the complexity of the model until the training results approach or exceed human experts.  You can do this by increasing the number of input features, choosing a different machine learning model, or increasing the number of layers in the NN.  If the training accuracy is poor, you need to improve this first before spending time improving the testing accuracy.

If the training accuracy is good but the testing accuracy is much worse than the training accuracy, you are probably overfitting.  Get or create more training data, and use regularization.